# Post link goes to 404 after changing permalink in multisite wordpress nginx server

Tags: wordpress, nginx, multisite, nginx-config

I have use worpdress multisite in nginx server.

before change my permalink will be like below

```
/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%-%post_id%.html
```

But I want permalink like

```
/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%/
```

But this is not working.
with index.php my link rediect to sitename.com/.html without index.php my link goes to 404

my config file try_files is

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /core/index.php?$args;
```

Comment: check you htaccess permission

Comment: @HarshKhare nginx server does not read htaccess. So it doesn't makes any changes to site.